# Storing and passing credentials to a remote system securely for service install during software deployment with COTS

Tags: windows, active-directory, remote

**Some background:**

- There is an array of Windows Server PCs being managed with Manage Engine Desktop Central
- There are software installers and scripts that require account credentials to install some services that run under a specific account (assuming it's service account per PC or service account per service)
- Manage Engine can save AD credentials and use them for its "Run As" option to execute the installer
- There doesn't seem to be a way to pass the AD credentials saved in Manage Engine to be used as script or executable parameters

**Question:**

Is there a way to (a) securely store credentials and (b) to securely pass those credentials to an installer or script executed using remote management software in an automated fashion?

Not married to MEDC for this purpose, just need to be able to deploy installers and scripts in an automatic scheduled way, ideally using COTS but custom baked solution is OK too if it's significantly better than a COTS option.